# Which is the first, non-Western, (written) description of the female orgasm?

Tags: sexuality, western-civilisation, sex

Which is the first, non-Western, (written) description of the female orgasm? Hildegard von Bingen wrote about around 1100, which is, AFAIK, the first known mention of it, but she was part of the Western tradition.

Comment: What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? What did you find? Please help us to help you. Can you explain why the relevant Wikipedia pages and google searches didn't answer the question?  [SE sites work best if the questions are supported by preliminary research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/2085030)

Comment: I would start a search in the [Kamasutra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kama_Sutra) (Indian and old)

Comment: @sempaiscuba My own research found Hildegard von Bingen but nothing else.